# How to perform Mipmapping in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I am learning WebGL and reading the book 'WebGL Programming Guide'. However, the book has omitted the topic on texture mipmapping. I tried to search the official OpenGL ES website but could not seem to get an answer to my question. Neither has anyone asked a similar question in StackOverflow.

Could someone show me, from the start to the end, how to perform texture mipmapping in WebGL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In WebGL, you can upload mip maps manually — that's what the `level` parameter is in [`gl.texImage2D`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) — or you can just upload level 0 and then use [`gl.generateMipmap`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml) to have them generated for you.

Once your mip maps are generated, use [`gl.texParameteri`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) to set a `gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` of `gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` (the default value), `gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST` or `gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

Mip mapping should then be used to sample that texture.

My understanding is that it should be as simple as using `gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D)` and e.g. `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR)`.

Comment: If we were to load the mipmaps manually, must we specify all mipmap levels until 1*1 is reached? I tried using just level 0 and level 1, loading two completely different images, but the canvas was just blank. The level-0 image is 256*256, while the level-1 image is 128*128.

Comment: Yes you need to specify all mipmap levels

Comment: [Here's an article that covers mipmapping in WebGL](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-textures/). For example you should know `gl.generateMipmap` won't work for textures that have dimensions that are not a power of 2.